# Time series forecasting with 5-min intervals

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, forecasting

I have a dataset with three columns **Time**, **Inside_Temperature**, and **Outside_Temperature** and I want to predict/forecast the inside temperature. I have extracted two more columns from **Time** columns which are **AM/PM** or **Day/Night**. I've tried the different machine and deep learning models but the linear regression model gives me some better results. But the issue is that this model is also overfitting when I increase the layers its accuracy goes down, same for parameters. So what is the best way to do hyperparameter tuning? and how can I handle this 5-min interval data? Your suggestions/help are welcome.

**Plot of the data**

[image]

**Plot of the weekly data**

[image]

**Plot of the Monthly data**

[image]

I've tried these parameters on it:

[image]